# Parsing through Group Boxes (Form Controls)

Tags: excel, vba

I've been searching through StackOverflow and all over the internet for hours now and can't find anything.

I am trying to parse through about 100 Form Control Group Boxes. Within each Group Box are 5 Option Boxes. I'm trying to do a "reset" for the questionnaire so I'm trying to set each Group Box  of Option Boxes to the final option box.

How do I see whether each option box in the group box is checked and then set each row to the fifth option box?

Comment: On a form,  or on a worksheet?

Comment: @TimWilliams It would be on a worksheet

Comment: Do the group boxes and/or option buttons (boxes?) have a consistent naming scheme?

Comment: ...asking because it's not too clear how you'd identify the 5th option button.

Comment: @TimWilliams Not really, I am thinking I can just go through and uncheck them all. Not necessarily the functionality I was looking for, but it serves the same purpose in general

Comment: If your option buttons are grouped (so that only one in each group can be "on") then it seems like you couldn't uncheck them all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From What I understood you want the last option button in all the groupboxes to be checked. Then I think you dont have to 'explicitly' write a loop through all the group boxes but just a loop through the options buttons and set the value to 1.

```
Dim Option_Button As OptionButton

For Each Option_Button In Worksheets("Sheet1").OptionButtons
    Option_Button.Value = 1
Next Option_Button
```

Not sure if its the best approach but I hope it helps.